# Best way to update json payload from cucumber feature file

Tags: java, rest-assured, pojo, jackson-databind

I have a complex Json which acts like a input to a webservice. I have created necessary POJO classes for it and I am using Jackson object mapper in my code.

What could be the best way to update the partial Json data from cucumber data tables?

Thanks in advance !!!

**Original Json:**

```
{
    "accNum": "Dummy_Account",
    "customerData": {
        "customerName": "Dummy_Name",
        "customerAddress": "Dummy_Address"
        
    },
    "accountData": {
        "cashAccountRef": "Dummy",
        "acntCrncy": "EUR",
        "foreignCurrencyAccounts": [
            {
                "foreignCurrency": "USD",
                "foreignCrncyAcntRef": "Dummy2"
                
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

**Cucumber Feature File**

```
Given Prepare Input request for below data
      | accNum                                                 | 12345   |
      | customerData.customerName                              | New Name|
      | accountData.foreignCurrencyAccounts[0].foreignCurrency | EUR     |
```

**Final Json to be passed as input**

```
{
    "accNum": "12345",
    "customerData": {
        "customerName": "New Name",
        "customerAddress": "Dummy_Address"
        
    },
    "accountData": {
        "cashAccountRef": "Dummy",
        "acntCrncy": "EUR",
        "foreignCurrencyAccounts": [
            {
                "foreignCurrency": "EUR",
                "foreignCrncyAcntRef": "Dummy2"
                
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For such purpose Karate is better option then Rest-Assured

Answer (score 1):

I found only this way

```
((ObjectNode) parent).putRawValue(valueOfKeyToModify, new RawValue(newValue));
```

The problem arises when there are many identical keys. And then you need to read the tree and go around it until it matches exactly the key that needs to be changed.

And if you need to lay string, then you must also specify quotes, since it lays the raw value

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using POJO then stick to this approach. Using setter to update value of the key, of course you can use builder style for setter to make it more easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @lucasnguyen17.  In my step definition I have read cucumber datatable as map - Map<String, String> data = table.asMap(String.class, String.class); 
And building the pojo like - 
var requestBody = objectMapper.readValue(file, ModifyCustomerRequest.class);

Below line works fine to update the existing payload -
requestBody.accountData.acntCrncy="INR";

Do you know how can i update multiple fields in the payload? Something like below which is giving me error-
data.forEach((k,v) -> requestBody.k=v );

Comment: You can ask a new question to help people fully understand your problem. Asking in comment is not a good way.